# Syntax for using find() in caching elements in an object literal

Tags: javascript

Whats the correct syntax for defining `$item:`?

So far I have:

```
var Animations = {

    el: {
        $body:      $('html, body'),
        $landing:       $('.landing'),
        $item:      $landing.find($('.item'))
    },

    init: function() { ..etc }
}
```

I've tried using `this` and `Animations.el.//element//` but cannot read property.

Comment: inside the literal you can not yet use the property so it would have to be function that can be evaluated and return what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to a member of an object literal within an object literal (because its not fully constructed at the point you attempt to do so), here:

```
$item: $landing.find($('.item'))
```

`$landing` is undefined.

Assign to `$item` in your `init()` method.

```
init: function() { 
    this.el.$item = this.el.$landing.find($('.item'));
}
```

Comment: I pick this only because it fits more with what im doing and there's the explaination of why the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
(...)
$item: this.Animations.el.$landing.find($('.item'))
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it outside initialization

```
var Animations = {
    el: {}
};

Animations.el.$body = $('html, body');
Animations.el.$landing = $('.landing');
Animations.el.$item = Animations.el.$landing.find($('.item'));
Animations.init = function() { ..etc }
```